# Working on my first h5 canvas game, trouble with the game loop (snake)

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas

So this is what the game loop looks like. I just set it through setInterval()
and it starts by clearing the screen and drawing the hud. After calculating the movement, then drawing everything, and checking collisions (I've had no trouble with these) I was hoping that once the player loses they could restart the game.

Currently all it does is calls window.location.reload() and goes back to the start menu. 
A player loses when they either hit a wall or collide with themselves.

this is calculated in the checkcollision() function, and I tried clearInterval(game); and that hardly works. I assumed it had something to do with checkcollision() being inside the game loop and tried using a series of return statements. that didn't work, I also tried moving the game stats and functions (score, ect) into a game object and trying to restart the game by making a new game object. but all that did was make them overlap, even with the same reference.

I'm very confused and wondering if I've just gone too far down the wrong path. Like I mean it works fine (on chome/safari/ff, is there a way to get canvas to work with IE?) but I just want to get a decent pausing/restarting system.

Here's my code, but you can also check out what I have working so far and inspect the full code [here](http://web.ncf.ca/fw769/Templates/livetesting/snakehtml5.html)

```
var game=setInterval(function(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
                if(score>localStorage.highscore){localStorage.highscore=score}
                hud();
                snakeMove();
                draw();
                checkCollision();
                },1000/60);
```

Comment: Where is the `clearInterval`? I think that would work.

Comment: _"I just want to get a decent pausing/restarting system."_ - A pause system? `if (isPaused) return;` as the first line of your loop function should handle that (where presumably you have some functions not shown that handle key-states and could set `isPaused` as appropriate). As far as a restart, do you not also need to reset some variables, like the starting position and so forth?

Comment: you should use requestAnimationFrame - http://jsfiddle.net/ghjKC/3/

Comment: @supernova: Not unless the game logic can deal with a variable timestep. Since `request­Animation­Frame` has a variable frame rate, your code has to be able to deal with that or you'll get funky results depending on the system's load.

Comment: yea ofc, you would have to seperate the physics update loop from the render loop which should be done anyways.